# Storing 1D array to 2D

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I store a 1D array of 9 into a 2D array of 3x3? This is my current attempt:

```
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if (i = 0)
        {
            a[i][j] = (int)data1[j];
        }
        if (i = 1)
        {
            a[i][j] = (int)data1[j + 3];
        }
        if (i = 2)
        {
            a[i][j] = (int)data1[j + 6];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As Alex29954 pointed out you are using `=` instead of `==` to check conditions. That means you are using C/C++ and C# is just invalid tag. Note [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30283967/477420) works for both C/C#.

Comment: You shouldn't word your question in such a demanding way. Instead of "I want" you could say "I'm looking for". Just as a tipp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  a[i / 3][i % 3] = data[i];
}
```

And as ThisHandleNotInUse pointed out, MAYBE this one is more optimized depending on the circumstances and still scales to larger arrays with minor tweaking.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    a[i][j] = data[i + j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Less optimized than direct assignment since 3 isn't a power of two - unless you know something I don't and the compiler actually precomputes the i/3 and i%3...  If you're exclusively working with 9 -> 3x3 arrays, I would direct assign if I were trying to ensure "optimization."  If I were trying to assign arr[4225] to arr[65,65] - I'd probably use your method.  Or just write a quick string algorithm that produced a very long direct assignment line.

Comment: Perfect C/C++/C# - as tags specified :) Side note: depending on types of arrays `(int)` cast from OP's sample may still be necessary.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse - I bet OP used "optimized" as synonym of "correct", not "optimized for speed"...

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Logical equal sign must be written like this:`if (i == 0)`
This will check condition.

```
if (i=0)
```

Is not correct because you do assignement operator for i

You can try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
     if(i == 0)
     {
         a[i][j] = (int)data1[j];
     }
     if (i == 1)
     {
         a[i][j] = (int)data1[j+3];
     }
     if (i == 2)
     {
         a[i][j] = (int)data1[j+6];
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: That's not really an answer though is it?

Answer (score 0):

How optimized do you need this to be?  What does your array contain?  If your array contains structs, you're going to be copying them no matter what you do.  If it contains references, you're going to be copying them (the references) no matter what you do.

If I were regularly converting an array[9] to an array[3,3], I'd just do this:

(arr = Old Array)

```
Array[,] NewArr = new Array[,]{ { arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] }, {arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]}, {arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]} };
```

EDIT: commenter below pointed out you were using a jagged array and not a multidimensional one in which case, in C#, the syntax would be:

```
Array[][] NewArr = new Array[][]{ new Array[]{ arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] }, new Array[]{ arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]}, new Array[]{ arr[6], arr[7], arr[8] }  };
```

Comment: You need to improve guess skill :) - most likely OP have arrays of `int` based on cast - `(int)` (or some other numeric type), definitely not copying references.

Comment: Note that 2d array is different from jagged array shown in the question. Also you showing C# code which is unlikely to help OP based on type of errors accepted by OP's compiler (`=` instead of `==` is warning in C/C++ and error in C#).

Comment: I thought I was under the C# tag...  I just noticed the C++ tag when you mentioned that.  And, good catch, I should have noticed he was using a jagged array.

Comment: Indeed it is marked as C#... and looks C# - just probably not what OP mean. So it is perfectly fair to answer in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in c++, if(I=2) is incorrect it should be if (I==2) and I'm not sure why you need that

One possible solution is to have two nested for loops as you already have and this code: a[i][j]=data[j*3+i]. No if is needed then.